# New line should start at first column

Tags: indentation

When I enter a new line the cursor always jumps to the column which was the starting column the line before! I would like for the curser to stay in the first column until I hit enter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, this is caused by `electric-indent`. You can toggle it globally by running <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>`electric-indent-mode`</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>.

In an init file, you can disable it using `(electric-indent-mode -1)`.

Comment: thx that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to LindyDancer's answer, this behavior depends on the indentation rules used by the major mode.  So if you're writing text, you might like `paragraph-indent-text-mode` or `paragraph-indent-minor-mode`.